# How did Morgoth manage to chain Maedhros to a peak of Thangorodrim?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

After arriving with his father and majority of the Noldor and fighting the forces of Angband,Maedhros was taken captive and brought before Morgoth, then was stripped of clothing and hung from a high point on a peak of Thangorodrim then later on rescued by his cousin Fingon. my point is,how did Morgoth or whoever chained him do it?

The peaks of Thangorodrim were insanely tall peaks on top of Angband.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The peaks of Thangorodrim were insanely tall peaks on top of Angband.

A tunnel ran  under the Iron Mountains from Thangorodrim in the south to Angband in the North.  Thangorodrim was built over the entrance to the tunnel and was the gatehouse of Angband.

People have been building and maintaining and repairing tall towers for hundreds and thousands of years.  There is a 36 foot tall statue of William Penn 547 feet above the ground at the top of the tower of the Philadelphia, Pennsylvania city hall.  It is a custom to dress the statue in a giant team jersey when a Philadelphia team wins a championship.  I think that the maintenance crew could find a way to chain someone to the side of the tower if ordered to by a dictator.

It is a trivial problem to think of ways Maedhros could have been chained to the side of a Thangorodrim tower.  With the available evidence it probably  is an impossible problem to deduce which way was used.